# Does the the field of tribology include the study of adhesives?

Tags: adhesive, tribology

Does the field of Tribology include the study of adhesives in addition to the study of lubricants?

Answer (score 4):

### No, it does not.

I do not think that adhesive science people have managed to come up with a fancy name like the lubrication folks.

Comment: I was thinking tribology was a generalized study of the physical interaction of material surfaces. It seems like a very narrow specialization.

Comment: It is only the study of wear between bodies.

Comment: FYI, and in case you did not know already, the first part of the name `tribo` is a derivate of the greek word for friction or generally *the act of rubbing something against something else*.

Comment: As long as we're mangling greek stems, I suggest "kratology" based on similar principles as the  "tribiology".

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know what tribology is, but tribiology?

Comment: @SolarMike. It's the study of the third level of biology: life that's advanced enough to have invented autocorrect.